# Property X does not exist in v-for loop

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am currently using Nuxt 3 and i facing this error.

in the `v-if` it says that `option` does not exist but it clearly does. How can i fix this bug, or can i ignore this bug with TS?

```
<template>
    <div ref="opt_el" tabindex="-1" @blur="isOpen = false" class="flex flex-col">
        <i @click="isOpen = !isOpen"
            class="text-gray-700  flex mx-auto ml-auto text-xl cursor-pointer fa-solid px-4 py-2 active:bg-gray-100 rounded hover:bg-gray-50 fa-ellipsis-vertical"></i>
        <div class=" relative">
            <transition name="fadeDropdown" mode="out-in">
                <div v-if="isOpen" class=" right-0  top-1 w-52 bg-white z-50 absolute border border-b-0 rounded">

                    <div v-for="option in options" :key="option.value" v-if="option.show(param)"
                        @click="exec(option.event)"
                        class="bg-white cursor-pointer select-none hover:bg-gray-50 active:bg-gray-100 w-full border-b p-2 text-gray-700">
                        {{ option.name }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </transition>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { DropdownDotOptionT } from "types"
let isOpen = ref(false)
let opt_el = ref<HTMLElement>()
let { param, options } = defineProps({
    options: {
        default: [] as DropdownDotOptionT[]
    },
    param: {
        default: null
    }
})


function exec(event: DropdownDotOptionT["event"]) {
    isOpen.value = false
    event(param)
}


watch(isOpen, (newValue) => {
    if (newValue) {
        nextTick(() => {

            opt_el.value?.focus()

        })

    }
})

</script>
```

Comment: I think this happens when you are declaring styles for vue inconsistently try the following script: https://pastebin.com/nRKRTDeq

Comment: It's a runtime error or a TS error? Mind sharing the exact one?